# How to find mp3 files on a remote server using Powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell

I have created a powershell script to search for mp3 files on my workstation.
This is successful on my workstation, how can I run this on my network of 80 workstations?

```
$strComputers = Get-Content -Path "C:\ARM\computernames.txt"
[bool]$firstOutput = $true
foreach($strComputer in $strComputers)
{
$colFiles = Get-Wmiobject -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
-computername $strComputer `
-Query "Select * from CIM_DataFile `
Where Extension = 'mp3'"
foreach ($objFile in $colFiles)
{
if($objFile.FileName -ne $null)
{
$filepath = $objFile.Drive + $objFile.Path + $objFile.FileName + "." `
+ $objFile.Extension;
$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" `
+ $filepath `
+ "'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_LogicalFileOwner ResultRole=Owner"

$colOwners = Get-Wmiobject -namespace "root\CIMV2" `
-computername $strComputer `
-Query $query
$objOwner = $colOwners[0]
$user = $objOwner.ReferencedDomainName + "\" + $objOwner.AccountName
$output = $strComputer + "," + $filepath + "," + $user + "," + $objFile.FileSize/1KB + "," + $objFile.LastModified
if($firstOutput)
{
Write-output $output | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath "C:\ARM\pstdetails.csv"
$firstOutput = $false
}
else
{
Write-output $output | Out-File -Encoding ascii -filepath "C:\ARM\pstdetails.csv" -append
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: When I run the ps1 file with adding few computer names in "computernames.txt" file i get the below error



PS C:\Users\s-t.CONSULT-ALTIUS> C:\Users\s-t.CONSULT-ALTIUS\Desktop\mp3.ps1
Get-Wmiobject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At C:\Users\s-t.CONSULT-ALTIUS\Desktop\mp3.ps1:5 char:13
+ $colFiles = Get-Wmiobject -namespace "root\CIMV2" `

Comment: this error occurs because you don't have permission to query the remote computers. try adding the `-credential` parameter

Comment: Any Suggestions on adding parameter as I am new to Powershell

Comment: from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315379.aspx `When using Get-WmiObject to connect to a remote computer, the remote computer must be running WMI and, under the default configuration, the account you are using must be in the local administrators group on the remote computer. The remote system does not need to have Windows PowerShell installed. This allows you to administer operating systems that are not running Windows PowerShell, but do have WMI available.`

Comment: @SachinTiwari you'll need to create a PSCredential Object, store it in a variable like `$cred` and then use it like this `gwmi -credential $cred`. Information on how to create PSCredentials and work with Secure Strings here: https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-credentials-how-to-encrypt-a-password/

Comment: What, are you are going to delete all their wonderful music?, or are you just going to leech it....

Comment: lol I am not gonna delete it but will make sure I have copies of all the music :)